# Unable to display data in data table dynamically. ( Angular 6 )

Tags: angular, datatable, angular6, angular-datatables

I am using angular data tables. I am trying to change data in them. I have 6 methods performing different calculations and pushing data into array.

I have 6 buttons. On button click, I am calling respective method and after performing calculation. I am pushing data into array (**storiesOfIndicators**)

**Problem Statement**

Clicking on button for first time shows table correctly but when i click next button than data is not showing properly and pagination status shows the result of first method result. Data table is not rendering properly. Basically pagination is not working

Method 1->

```
storiesWhomDefectTimeIsGreaterThanDev() {
    this.storiesOfIndicators = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.global.data.length; i++) {
        if (this.global.data[i].defectTime > this.global.data[i].devTime) {
            this.storiesOfIndicators.push(this.global.data[i])
        }
    }
}
```

**My Table**

```
<table id="indicators" *ngIf="storiesOfIndicators.length > 0" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Story Id</th>
            <th>Story Name</th>
            <th>Time Spent (Days)</th>
            <th>Estimated Time (Days)</th>
            <th>Threshold Value</th>
            <th>Aggregated Estimated Time (Days)</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let story of storiesOfIndicators">
            <td>{{story.id}}</td>
            <td>{{story.name}}</td>
            <td>{{convertValueToDays(story.timeSpent)}}</td>
            <td>{{convertValueToDays(story.originalEstimates)}}</td>
            <td>{{story.threshold}}</td>
            <td>{{convertThresholdValue(story.originalEstimates)}}</td>
            <td>{{story.status}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Tried Solution** 
I tried to add `this.dtrigger.next()` on the start of each method but its not working.

I again tried by calling this method at start of my method but not working either it instead remove my css/pagination/search but data is  displaying correctly.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.next();
}
rerender() {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        dtInstance.destroy();
        this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
}
```

Comment: It's a little bit complex to understand your pagination problem without an example. Can you provide us a stackblitz or plunker example ? Thanks.

Comment: see [this](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/with-options) for pagination documentation

Comment: @Tushar Walzade I wanna reinitialize the table. Data and pagination not are functioning properly.

Answer (score 0):

Its because table is rendering first then data is loaded after api call. I used `ngIf` to hide the table until the data is fetched, then it will load correctly. It's just an experimental.

**html**

```
<table datatable  class="table" *ngIf="flg"  >
```

**.ts file**

```
flg: boolean = false;

this._UsersService.GetUser(Mobile, Department, Section, Branch, designation_Id, group).subscribe((data: ResponseData) => {
  if (data.data.length > 0) {
      this.flg = true;

      this.UserList = data.data;
   }

      console.log(this.UserList);
},
error => { this.errorMessage = <any>error },
  () => {     
});
```